# What's the difference between cheap and expensive domain registrars?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

A few years ago I registered a domain with Network Solutions. In recent years I've been using cheaper services such as namecheap, powerpipe etc.

Every time that I need to renew some of the older domains with Network Solutions I am surprised at how much expensive they are. What is the reason for the price differences between the services? Why should I use a service like Network Solutions if there are so many companies out there that offer domain registration for a very cheap price?

Comment: NS is very expensive, however, I have used their promotions to buy domains at less than half their price, sometimes even lower than GoDaddy which is what I think a reasonable price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Price differences can be explained for the following reasons:

- Support and customer service. Having people on call 24/hours a day to answer questions, and fix problems is expensive, cheaper hosts don't have the money to offer this support. Redundancy may be better for the more expensive players as well.
- Name recognition. Companies that advertise heavily have to pay for the marketing, but also companies with big name recognition can charge more as people tend to go with brands over no names due to a sense of quality (this may be undeserved!). Put simply if I have only heard of network solutions and no other company I am vastly more likely to become their customer.
- No need to discount. Discounters are trying to gain more customers usually at the expense of existing players. Discounting is a way of entering a mature market. The big names already have prominence and do not need to discount.
- Market. Companies that are primarily supporting large companies can charge way more than companies aiming at small users and personal websites. A company that’s hosting their single domain isn't looking to penny pinch, a guy who wants to host his blog is much more likely to be looking for a deal. Large companies in general are used to dropping large amounts of money on IT costs, and usually look for strong support contracts.

Answer (score 2):

I would nearly always buy on lowest price, but service is important too, so...

To analyze this, first of all, I will lay aside the really expensive registrars and also the really crappy services, both of which I would simply avoid, though others may have their reasons for choosing such services, I can see no point in paying 10 or 20 times the going rate for a domain, and neither can i see any point in saving mere pennies per year while sacrificing a decent registrar interface.

So aside from those providers my reasons for paying more/less within the remainder of the playing field in my opinion would go like this:

The two important things for me are A) quality/style/structure/capability etc of the domains control panel and B) provider support system. If I get a high quality control panel for my domains which has a fair bit of capability and this is backed up with quality support plus a decent help/knowledge base/community then I'd consider that worth extra money, how much really depends on how much time a person spends working with the domains and the capabilities they require ( dns zone, push etc )

That's how it *should* work ! But I have to tell you that in my experience the cheaper providers often paradoxically give more in this regard, which is why I tend to just buy on price in the end, even though I would still pay more if I had to.

Comment: Please use some paragraphs etc on your text.

Comment: The question was not about how to decide on which registrar to use or on your personal preferences but on why prices of different registrars are so different.

Comment: i think i AM answering the question - you cant answer that question without giving personal experiencei notice you criticised the other person who answered too .... AND I ALSO notice that you havent given an answer of your own !!!! do you think this is constructive..... all you're doing is confusing the OP if you ask me !!!!

Comment: @Kissaki ...and ALSO i happen to think it's rude not to reference where it says that i have to paragraph my answer - just because you use the word 'Please' does not make your comment polite - a polite thing to do would be to provide a link(to info which by the way i cant find so ??)

Comment: Eh?? You need rules or guides to make your answer, or even text in general, readable? Using Grammar, paragraphs and new lines as well as other text styling is something one should use individually and on his own to make it even/easily readable for others. A textblock with dots is not readable. Or scan-able at that. Why do you think pretty much every text-book and article out there uses newlines and paragraphs?

Comment: I did not answer the question because I could not. At least not in a way I would think that it is a good answer. By commenting on these answers I point out what I think does not make these questions useful or answers at all. That’s what this website and commenting is about.

Comment: Although you may not find it polite what I tell you, even after adding a please, it’s more of a subjective interpretation of my text. I did not intend to insult or annoy you, just to improve this site and the web by commenting.

Comment: By the way, I upvoted one answer because I found it useful (that’s what voting is about) and answering the question. Using voting and not providing my own answer, which would be inferior, is also what this site is about.

Comment: Please do not feel frustrated and pushed away from this site now, as I see you’re new to it. Read the FAQ on what this site is about, get a feeling for it by reading some and take comments as (constructive) feedback to improve everyones experience. We’re happy of every new active and productive member on this site.

Comment: i appreciate all you're comments though i think your initial comments belied your intentions. I feel they would be viewed by a typical newcomer as off-putting and negative because they were so stark. I am a member of several hundred communities and ( yes it does seem that stackexchange is quite different which is wonderful) but most people in the technical area are used to very low quality posts and comments, often high quality info written very badly; my point is that if stackexcange wants to be a source of high quality as it seems ( which i think is awesome ) then ...

Comment: i think us members will have to be more patient in dealing with people ( who like me ) haven't studied the rules as carefully as we should to know exactly how well to write the info .... in this case i assumed ( wrongly it seems ) that you were just causing trouble because i thought i was doing good answering the question - at the time i didn't realise that it needed to be properly laid out ... just my 2c

Comment: Sorry. I may be pretty direct at times, but mean no harm. I requested an edit on the answer to show what I meant with formatting and paragraphs. It will probably approved soon. On another note, I found the answer very confusing as you jump from "buy by price" to "service important too" to "buy by price in the end". Btw., you *can* edit your answer with your user-level, can’t you? Editing and improving answers is common on answers here so they are not only good to egos, but also for anyone finding the question, looking for useful and (very) good answers.

Comment: no worries .... "buy on price" ( in my part of the world anyway) means buy the cheapest, as opposed to the best quality; maybe that term is not international; I thought it was. I have re-edited (the edit) so hopefully it's clear now .... I think the question that the OP raised is a very good one but the industry is convoluted IMO .... hopefully you can see from my cleared up answer that a) i buy on price, b)i still need quality  c) some of the cheaper providers strangely give a better service ( which is why i buy on price in the first place)

Comment: A lot better. Especially the elaboration, giving your opinion a basis. Thanks.

Comment: I’m not a native en speaker, so buy on price may very well be the correct/another correct way to spell it.

Comment: no it's a phrase/expression ... as in "buy (based on cheapest available) price

Answer (score 1):

I have been developing and maintaining Web sites for a decade and I have used many different registrars and hosting services.

The best, by far, has been Network Solutions.

The #1 reason they are the best, for me, is their service.  You can always get someone on the phone to assist with your inquiry/issue.

Moreover, with NS, you do not have to worry about them shutting down and you losing your domain or the many other issues that can occur with smaller registrars and resellers.

When it comes to registrars, you get what you pay for.

Comment: So the point of your advertisement is … some are more expensive because of better and thus more expensive support?

Comment: You can call it an advertisement @Kissaki, but I was giving my honest opinion.  Yes, they cost more.  But they also give the best support, IMO.  OP asked specifically about NS and I answered.  BTW: I get nothing from NS for this. ;-)

Comment: Network Solutions is the grand-daddy of registrars.  Its the oldest and one of the most expensive.    I have never had an issue with support there, but you certainly pay more when you use them.

Comment: From my experience any registrar is better than Network Solutions, these guys are the worst really.